# pthreads - force thread to run

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have a function that is invoked from the main thread:

```
void create_thread() {    
    pthread_t bg_thread;
    pthread_create(&bg_thread, NULL, run_in_background, NULL);

    //wait here
    pthread_mutex_lock(&MAIN_MUTEX);
    pthread_cond_wait(&wakeUpMainThread, &MAIN_MUTEX);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&MAIN_MUTEX);

    pthread_cond_signal(wakeUpBgThread);
}
```

Here is the short version of the function that runs in background thread:

```
void* run_in_background(void* v) {                   
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  cond;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    //NOTE: wakeUpBgThread == cond
    save_condition_and_mutex(&cond, &mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&wakeUpMainThread);

        while( run_condition ) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

            do_smth();
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So the goal is:

```
1. Create a thread in the main one.
2. Make the main thread sleep until the signal from that thread.
3. Make the background thread sleep until the signal from the main thread.
4. Invoke the background thread from the main one.
```

The problem is: sometimes after the

```
 pthread_cond_signal(&wakeUpMainThread);
```

scheduler switches to the main thread immediately and fires the wake up signal for the background thread. After this scheduler switches back to the background thread and it starts waiting for the signal that has already been fired, so it sleeps forever.

Question: is there any way to force background thread to execute the code until the

```
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `pthread_mutex_lock` in `create_thread` needs to take place **before** `pthread_create`, not after it. Otherwise you have a race condition.

Comment: You're right that i should place that lock before but I don't think this is the real problem because the MAIN_MUTEX is used only when the new thread is created and nowhere else so it doesn't influence the background thread execution.

Comment: You need to lock *that same mutex*, `MAIN_MUTEX`, before calling ` pthread_cond_signal(&wakeUpMainThread);`.

Comment: Thanks. Already found the real problem. It was the deadlock in the part of the class that I didn't post here.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the code you posted also has a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use a semaphore?  Semaphore signals are not lost - they just increment the count & so the background thread *will* run agan after the semaphore is signaled, even if it has not actually got around to waiting on it yet.

Rgds,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best bet is to use a condition.  Have a mutex and a condition.  Main initializes both, grabs the mutex, creates the thread, then goes to sleep on the condition.  Child grabs the lock (after main waits on the condition) does the work (or alternatively does the work then grab the lock), and then signals the condition (you can decide whether to release the lock before or after the signal--important bit is that you grabbed it).  Main then wakes up and continues processing.

pthread_cond_wait() and friends is what you look at.

Answer (score 0):

You don't lock the mutex before your signal on main thread. If you want predictable behavior - you should lock the same mutex both before wait call and signal call.